# Unable to alter column name for a Hudi table in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue, apache-hudi

I'm unable to alter the column name of Hudi table .
spark.sql("ALTER TABLE customer_db.customer RENAME COLUMN subid TO subidentifier") unbable to change the column name.

A clear and concise description of the problem.

I'm unable to alter the column name of Hudi table .
spark.sql("ALTER TABLE customer_db.customer RENAME COLUMN subid TO subidentifier") code is unable to change the column name.

Getting the following error when trying to change the column using above code:
**RENAME COLUMN is only supported with v2 tables**

**To Reproduce**

```
import com.amazonaws.services.glue.GlueContext
import com.amazonaws.services.glue.util.{GlueArgParser, Job}
import org.apache.hudi.DataSourceWriteOptions
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.{DataFrame, SaveMode, SparkSession}
import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf, SparkContext}

import scala.collection.JavaConverters._
import scala.collection.mutable

object ReportingJob {

  var spark: SparkSession = _
  var glueContext: GlueContext = _

  def main(inputParams: Array[String]): Unit = {

    val args: Map[String, String] = GlueArgParser.getResolvedOptions(inputParams, Seq("JOB_NAME").toArray)
    val sysArgs: mutable.Map[String, String] = scala.collection.mutable.Map(args.toSeq: _*)
   
    implicit val glueContext: GlueContext = init(sysArgs)
    implicit val spark: SparkSession = glueContext.getSparkSession

    import spark.implicits._
     
val partitionColumnName: String = "id"
    val hudiTableName: String = "Customer"
    val preCombineKey: String = "id"
    val recordKey = "id"
    val basePath= "s3://aws-amazon-uk/customer/production/"
    
    
   val df= Seq((123,"1","seq1"),(124,"0","seq2")).toDF("id","subid","subseq")
    
      val hudiCommonOptions: Map[String, String] = Map(
        "hoodie.table.name" -> hudiTableName,
        "hoodie.datasource.write.keygenerator.class" -> "org.apache.hudi.keygen.ComplexKeyGenerator",
        "hoodie.datasource.write.precombine.field" -> preCombineKey,
        "hoodie.datasource.write.recordkey.field" -> recordKey,
        "hoodie.datasource.write.operation" -> "bulk_insert",
        //"hoodie.datasource.write.operation" -> "upsert",
        "hoodie.datasource.write.row.writer.enable" -> "true",
        "hoodie.datasource.write.reconcile.schema" -> "true",
        "hoodie.datasource.write.partitionpath.field" -> partitionColumnName,
        "hoodie.datasource.write.hive_style_partitioning" -> "true",
        // "hoodie.bulkinsert.shuffle.parallelism" -> "2000",
        //  "hoodie.upsert.shuffle.parallelism" -> "400",
        "hoodie.datasource.hive_sync.enable" -> "true",
        "hoodie.datasource.hive_sync.table" -> hudiTableName,
        "hoodie.datasource.hive_sync.database" -> "customer_db",
        "hoodie.datasource.hive_sync.partition_fields" -> partitionColumnName,
        "hoodie.datasource.hive_sync.partition_extractor_class" -> "org.apache.hudi.hive.MultiPartKeysValueExtractor",
        "hoodie.datasource.hive_sync.use_jdbc" -> "false",
        "hoodie.combine.before.upsert" -> "true",
        "hoodie.avro.schema.external.transformation" -> "true",
        "hoodie.schema.on.read.enable" -> "true",
        "hoodie.datasource.write.schema.allow.auto.evolution.column.drop" -> "true",
        "hoodie.index.type" -> "BLOOM",
        "spark.hadoop.parquet.avro.write-old-list-structure" -> "false",
        DataSourceWriteOptions.TABLE_TYPE.key() -> "COPY_ON_WRITE"
      )


 
      df.write.format("org.apache.hudi")
        .options(hudiCommonOptions)
        .mode(SaveMode.Overwrite)
        .save(basePath+hudiTableName)
        
        spark.sql("ALTER TABLE customer_db.customer RENAME COLUMN subid TO subidentifier")
  commit()
  }

  def commit(): Unit = {
    Job.commit()
  }


  def init(sysArgs: mutable.Map[String, String]): GlueContext = {

    val conf = new SparkConf()

    conf.set("spark.serializer", "org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer")
    conf.set("spark.sql.legacy.parquet.int96RebaseModeInRead", "CORRECTED")
    conf.set("spark.sql.legacy.parquet.int96RebaseModeInWrite", "CORRECTED")
    conf.set("spark.sql.legacy.parquet.datetimeRebaseModeInRead", "CORRECTED")
    conf.set("spark.sql.legacy.parquet.datetimeRebaseModeInWrite", "CORRECTED")
    conf.set("spark.sql.avro.datetimeRebaseModeInRead", "CORRECTED")
    val sparkContext = new SparkContext(conf)
    glueContext = new GlueContext(sparkContext)
    Job.init(sysArgs("JOB_NAME"), glueContext, sysArgs.asJava)
    glueContext

  }
}
```

Steps to reproduce the behavior:

1. I'm using AWS glue job to run the above job.
2. In Dependent JARs path
   hudi-spark3-bundle_2.12-0.12.1
   calcite-core-1.16.0
   libfb303-0.9.3
3. Run the above code.

**Expected behavior**

spark.sql("ALTER TABLE customer_db.customer RENAME COLUMN subid TO subidentifier") should be able to rename a column name. Could you suggest any other way to rename the Hudi column name.

A clear and concise description of what you expected to happen.
Change Column name of a hudi table

**Environment Description**

- Hudi version : 0.12.1
- Spark version :3.3

Glue Version : 4

Jars used:
hudi-spark3-bundle_2.12-0.12.1
calcite-core-1.16.0
libfb303-0.9.3

- Storage (HDFS/S3/GCS..) :S3
- Running on Docker? (yes/no) : no

**Additional context**

Add any other context about the problem here.

**Stacktrace**

**Exception in User Class: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException : RENAME COLUMN is only supported with v2 tables.**
at org.apache.spark.sql.errors.QueryCompilationErrors$.operationOnlySupportedWithV2TableError(QueryCompilationErrors.scala:506) ~[spark-catalyst_2.12-3.3.0-amzn-1.jar:3.3.0-amzn-1]
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.ResolveSessionCatalog$$anonfun$apply$1.applyOrElse(ResolveSessionCatalog.scala:94) ~[spark-sql_2.12-3.3.0-amzn-1.jar:3.3.0-amzn-1]
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.ResolveSessionCatalog$$anonfun$apply$1.applyOrElse(ResolveSessionCatalog.scala:49) ~[spark-sql_2.12-3.3.0-amzn-1.jar:3.3.0-amzn-1]
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.$anonfun$resolveOperatorsUpWithPruning$3(AnalysisHelper.scala:138) ~[spark-catalyst_2.12-3.3.0-amzn-1.jar:3.3.0-amzn-1]
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.CurrentOrigin$.withOrigin(TreeNode.scala:177) ~[spark-catalyst_2.12-3.3.0-amzn-1.jar:3.3.0-amzn-1]
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.$anonfun$resolveOperatorsUpWithPruning$1(AnalysisHelper.scala:138) ~[spark-catalyst_2.12-3.3.0-amzn-1.jar:3.3.0-amzn-1]
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper$.allowInvokingTransformsInAnalyzer(AnalysisHelper.scala:323) ~[spark-catalyst_2.12-3.3.0-amzn-1.jar:3.3.0-amzn-1]
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.resolveOperatorsUpWithPruning(AnalysisHelper.scala:134) ~[spark-catalyst_2.12-3.3.0-amzn-1.jar:3.3.0-amzn-1]
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.resolveOperatorsUpWithPruning$(AnalysisHelper.scala:130) ~[spark-catalyst_2.12-3.3.0-amzn-1.jar:3.3.0-amzn-1]
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.resolveOperatorsUpWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:30) ~[spark-catalyst_2.12-3.3.0-amzn-1.jar:3.3.0-amzn-1]
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.resolveOperatorsUp(AnalysisHelper.scala:111) ~[spark-catalyst_2.12-3.3.0-amzn-1.jar:3.3.0-amzn-1]
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.resolveOperatorsUp$(AnalysisHelper.scala:110) ~[spark-catalyst_2.12-3.3.0-amzn-1.jar:3.3.0-amzn-1]
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.resolveOperatorsUp(LogicalPlan.scala:30) ~[spark-catalyst_2.12-3.3.0-amzn-1.jar:3.3.0-amzn-1]
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.ResolveSessionCatalog.apply(ResolveSessionCatalog.scala:49) ~[spark-sql_2.12-3.3.0-amzn-1.jar:3.3.0-amzn-1]
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.ResolveSessionCatalog.apply(ResolveSessionCatalog.scala:43) ~[spark-sql_2.12-3.3.0-amzn-1.jar:3.3.0-amzn-1]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see you did't set `spark.sql.catalog.spark_catalog=org.apache.spark.sql.hudi.catalog.HoodieCatalog` in your spark conf. This is needed to use relation V2, and benefit from the schema evolution feature.

Comment: Adding the below config helped me alter the column.  conf.set("spark.sql.catalog.spark_catalog","org.apache.spark.sql.hudi.catalog.HoodieCatalog")
conf.set("spark.sql.extensions","org.apache.spark.sql.hudi.HoodieSparkSessionExtension") plus this code spark.sql("set hoodie.schema.on.read.enable=true")
spark.sql("ALTER TABLE customer_db.customer RENAME COLUMN subid TO subidentifier") . The issue is resolved thanks.

Answer (score 0):

So a few things:

- As you are using `Glue 4.0`, you don't really need to add any external hudi jars. It supports Hudi version `0.12.1`
- Also most **importantly**, to enable `hudi` you actually need to add a Glue job parameter `--datalake-formats` with value `hudi`
- You need to set `spark.serializer=org.apache.spark.serializer.KyroSerializer` and `spark.sql.hive.convertMetastoreParquet=false`, these parameters help Spark to handle Hudi tables correctly and these configurations can be set in `SparkConf` when you are initializing a `SparkSession` or can add these as job parameters in `--conf` with value `spark.serializer=org.apache.spark.serializer.KyroSerializer --conf spark.sql.hive.convertMetastoreParquet=false`

Also, you can get all these details from Glue [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-programming-etl-format-hudi.html).

Comment: thank you for the suggestion, I'm aware of the datalake-format hudi option , my issue has been resolved by adding the config mentioned above in parsini answer.